# Android databinding to a custom view

Tags: android, android-view, android-livedata

What I'm trying to do is pass a live data through to a custom view

What I'd like to do:

```
<com.mastherhealth.masterbilling.views.DashboardCard
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_card_size"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dashboard_card_size"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dashboard_card_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dashboard_card_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_card_center_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_card_center_margin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dashboard_doctor_spinner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:name="Saved"
    app:number="@{`` + viewModel.savedClaimsLiveData}"/>
```

Where the viewModel.saveClaimsLiveData is a LiveData That I'm going to be getting from my repository.

my **attrs.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="DashboardCard">
        <attr name="name" format="string"/>
        <attr name="fontAwesome" format="string"/>
        <attr name="number" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I have a DashboardCard class that extends CardView, sets the name and number the way I'd like them to look.

I'm currently getting

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:number' with parameter type java.lang.String on com.mastherhealth.masterbilling.views.DashboardCard.
```

Comment: Did you add `setNumber(String number)` method of your custom view?

Comment: have defined the custom attribute "number" anywhere?

Comment: It's defined in the attrs file, and when I just use app:number="27" it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) for a custom attribute.

```
@BindingAdapter("number")
fun bindNumber(view: View, number: String) {
    // ...
}
```